# Nestjs Config access to config in bootstrap level

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-config

According to this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-config)  you import your config in AppModule.
I'm trying to access to config in bootstrap level in my main.ts file.
Something like this:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  if (config.get('swagger.enabled'))
  {
    initSwagger(app);
  }
  await app.listen(8080);
```

The problem that I don't have access to config in this point, only other moudle will get access to config like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService,
                  private readonly config: ConfigService) {}
}
```

My question: How to access to 'nestjs-config' in bootstrap level

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your `main.ts` you can do `const config = app.get(ConfigService)` and have access to your `ConfigService` after you have created your server, but before you start listening on the port.

Comment: How if the app wasn't initialized, for example when using microservice with Kafka?