# How to pass configs from config service to Nest.js decorator?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I use @UseInterceptors with FilesInterceptor from @nestjs/platform-express. FilesInterceptor allows me to pass some configs (like files storage folder). I would like to pass not exact values (e.g. 'public') but to get them from configService.

From this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59828094/13128344) I understood why calling this.configService from UseInterceptors results in undefined.

```
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('cat_pic', 2, this.configService.get('storageConfigs')))
```

So how can I pass configs to FilesInterceptor? Or how to access a service if I move file interceptor function to a separate module?

Comment: I changed `ConfigModule` to use a fixed configuration object (it includes env and other variables). I require that object directly where I cannot access `configService`

Answer (score 7):

One option you have is to call `config()` from the `dotenv` package to load everything into `process.env` in your `main.ts`. You can still use the `ConfigModule` and `ConfigService` everywhere else, but in decorators you would use that `process.env.storageConfigs` variable.

Another option would be a package like [@golevelup/profiguration](https://github.com/golevelup/ts-ecosystem/blob/master/libs/profiguration/README.md) which is a configuration service that *can* be used in decorators because of the way it was written.

Comment: In Nest.js v9, if you include your decorator in the `providers` block for a module that has access to configService, you can then have the configService injected into your decorator with e.g. `constructor(protected readonly configService: ConfigService) {}` and use it as you would anywhere else. Wasn't very discoverable, hope this might help someone!

Comment: @miek Just because that _class instance_ has access to the injected config service doesn't mean that decorators of that class will. It's very dependent on how the decorator is written, and in many cases, like `@UseInterceptors()` the `ConfigService` **can not** be accessed

Comment: Oh, that’s unfortunate. Very much an YMMV thing, then. Thanks for the heads-up!