# NestJs Using Environment Configuration on @Cron decorator

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, node-cron

I am building a nestJs application, with scheduling and configuration. I want to be able to configure my Cron with my environment variable but it does not seems to work.

app.module.ts :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    SchedulingModule,
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

scheduling.service.ts (from my SchedulingModule) :

```
@Cron(process.env.CRON_VALUE)
scheduledJob() {
  this.logger.log('Scheduled : Job');
  ...
}
```

.env :

```
...
CRON_VALUE=0 4 * * *
...
```

Apparently at the moment the value is checked it's empty. I got the following error :

```
(node:55016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_isAMomentObject' of undefined
    at new CronTime (/Users/antoinegrenard/Documents/Projet/b4finance/service-scheduling/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:42:50)
    at new CronJob (/Users/antoinegrenard/Documents/Projet/b4finance/service-scheduling/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:527:19)
    at /Users/antoinegrenard/Documents/Projet/b4finance/service-scheduling/node_modules/@nestjs/schedule/dist/scheduler.orchestrator.js:56:29 
    ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass configs from config service to Nest.js decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376082/how-to-pass-configs-from-config-service-to-nest-js-decorator)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to get env values in decorators.

I had to do it this way :

```
constructor(private schedulerRegistry: SchedulerRegistry) {}

onModuleInit() {
  const job = new CronJob(process.env. CRON_VALUE, () => {
    // What you want to do here
  });

  this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob(name, job);
  job.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem you should load the config on your service again:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Comment: Is there a "nestjs" way to do that ?

Comment: @Youba Unfortunately there is not, this is a limitation of its Config system because it evaluates `.env` AFTER all the imports and decorators are resolved. You have to manually ensure that .env is populated before other files are imported in order to have dynamic decorator values

Comment: Yes, you can't either pass a value from config service to a decorators, moreover you can't load the config from main.js when we working with Crons

Comment: I hope at least this solution works for you ^^

Comment: @Youba what about from your app.module?

Comment: @Youba Thanks for sharing your solution. That's what I ended up doing; adding it into app.module.ts (so that it will also work doing testing). I am amazed by Nest.js and how fun it most of the time is to work with, however, equally amazed at how "dumb" they made the ConfigModule.

Comment: If the project uses the NestJS config module to share the .env variables in all nestjs components, this module might have logic (e.g you load the .env.dev only if .env.local doesnt exist) - if you use require('dotenv').config() - the current file won't have the same .env file as the rest of the nestjs which is defined by the config module

Answer (score 0):

A way I made it work was like this

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

const getCronInterval = () => {
  dotenv.config();

  return process.env.FETCH_AND_SEND_DATA_CRON_INTERVAL;
};

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    private readonly service: MyService,
  ) {}

  @Cron(getCronInterval()) // Adjust the cron schedule as needed
  async doSomething() {
    ....
```